# MongoDB query to update fields with same name

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm using `mongodb version v3.4.2`

I have a collection with one document.

The document has a complex(not standard) structure that I don't know.

The structure of the document is something like this

```
{
    "time": 9281
    "object_1": [
        { "time": 8372 },
        { "time": 3234 }
    ],
    "object_2": {
        "time": 2928
    }
}
```

I need to change the values of all fields with name `"time"`.

Can I do this with a single/multiple mongo query?

I tried with :

```
db.collection.update({}, {$set: {time: 999}})
db.collection.updateMany({}, {$set: {time: 999}})
```

but only top level occurrencies are updated with the new value.

After the document has been updated with the query, this should be the result:

```
{
    "time":999
    "object_1":[{"time":999},{"time":999}]
    "object_2":{"time":999}
}
```

Comment: do you want to set each `time` to constant value 999?

Comment: yes, that's what I'm trying to do